# SSIS Package stops running after validation

Tags: ssis

I have created an SSIS package that loads data from a CSV file to a staging table, then archives the CSV file. When I run the package using the package execute utility with file system as a source, it runs correctly - first validating, then executing each step.

However, when I import the package into the SSIS package store and execute it from there using MSDB using right click -> run package, none of the steps actually execute. Each step is validated successfully, but never executed. The package reports as being run successfully, and doesn't throw any errors.

Is there some type of setting that causes the package to only validate and not actually execute when run from the package store vs file system?

Comment: Does the account you're connecting to the SQL Server have the appropriate read and write access to the file system and table in question?  Do you have SSIS logging turned on in the package?  Validation is really just a very basic check; it won't reveal all errors.  I recommend logging OnError, OnPipelinePostEndOfRowset, OnPipelinePreEndOfRowset, OnPipelineRowsSent, OnPostExecute, OnPreExecute, OnTaskFailed, and OnWarning.

Comment: When the Foreach File Enumerator doesn't find a file, it doesn't throw an error, it simply reports back that no files were found. You'll also get that same ... warning I think, when the file system permissions prevent a package from listing files.