# Why is SSIS package stopping after validation steps and not running tasks?

Tags: ssis

I am working on an SSIS package in VS 2017 targeting SQL Server 2016. Sometimes when I go to run it (hit the Debug button), it doesn't run any tasks, it just goes through the validation steps and stops, showing the message in my screenshot. None of the tasks have green checkmarks or red x's. No errors or warnings in the Progress tab. I have to close and reopen the package for it to run, and then a few hours later, I'm usually back to this problem. Anyone know what could be causing this? Not sure if it will cause any issues when it runs from a server later, as it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499552/ssis-package-stops-running-after-validation) that went unanswered.

[image]

If it matters, the package archives some files, runs some Execute SQL tasks to run stored procedures in Oracle or SQL Server, then pulls data from the database and exports to csv files.

Comment: No, never resolved it, however it seems to work fine running on the server using SQL Server Agent (I passed the package on to a coworker who has never reported issues, at least). But I also didn't try reinstalling anything either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with SSDT 2017 targeting SQL Server 2016. Never found out what caused it as it happened intermittently. Uninstalled and [reinstalled SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools) and never had any problems again.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the idea. I will try uninstalling it!

Answer (score 0):

I unistalled all verisons of VS on my windows 2019 server machine. Did a clean installation of VS 2019 and then SSDT. Issue was fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that in my control flow the task was disabled. I re-enabled it in the control flow and reran it which solved it.